# GLSL Shader - change 'camera' position

Tags: opengl, camera, glsl

I'm trying to create some kind of 'camera' object with OpenGL. By changing its values, you can zoom in/out, and move the camera around. *(imagine a 2d world and you're on top of it).* This results in the variables `center.x`, `center.y`, and `center.z`.

```
attribute vec2 in_Position;
attribute vec4 in_Color;
attribute vec2 in_TexCoords;

uniform vec2 uf_Projection;
uniform vec3 center;

varying vec4 var_Color;
varying vec2 var_TexCoords;

void main() {
    var_Color = in_Color;
    var_TexCoords = in_TexCoords;
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x /  uf_Projection.x - center.x,
                       in_Position.y / -uf_Projection.y + center.y,
                                         0, center.z);
}
```

I'm using `uniform vec3 center` to manipulate the camera location. (I'm feeling it should be called an `attribute`, but I don't know for sure; I only know how to manipulate the `uniform` values. )

`uf_Projection` has values of half the screen height and width. This was already the case (forking someones code), and I can only assume it's to make sure the values in gl_Position are normalized?

Entering values for i.e. `center.x` does change the camera angle correctly. **However, it does not match the location at which certain things appear to be rendered.**

In addition to the question: how bad is the code?, I'm actually asking these concrete questions:

- What is `in_Position` supposed to be? I've seen several code examples use it, but no-one explains it. It's not explicitly defined either; which values does it take?
- What values is `gl_Position` supposed to take? `uf_Projection` seems to normalize the values, but when adding values (more than 2000) at `center.x`, it still works (correctly moved the screen).
- Is this the correct way to create a kind of "camera" effect? Or is there a better way? (the idea is that things that aren't on the screen, don't have to get rendered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions you ask can only be answered if one considers the bigger picture. In this case, this means we should have a look at the vertex shader and the typical *coordinate transformations* which are used for rendering.

The purpose of the vertex shader is to calculate a *clip space* position for each vertex of the object(s) to be drawn.
In this context, an object is just a sequence of geometrical primitives like points, lines or triangles, each specified by some vertices.

These verties typically specify some position with respect to some completely user-defined coorinate frame of reference. The space those vertex positions are defined in is typically called the *object space*.

Now the vertex shader's job is to *transform* from object space to clip space using some mathematical or algorithmical way. Typically, these transformation rules also implicitely or explicitetely consist of some "virtual camera", so that the object is transformd as if observed by said camera.

However, what rules are used, and how they are described, and which inputs are needed is completely free.

> What is `in_Position` supposed to be? I've seen several code examples use it, but no-one explains it. It's not explicitly defined either; which values does it take?

So `in_Position` in your case is just some attribute (meaning it is a value which is specified *per vertex*). The "meaning" of this attribute depends solely on how it is used. Since you are using it as input for some coordinate transformation, we could interpret it as meaning the *object space position of the vertex*. In your case, that is a 2D object space.The values it "takes" are completely up to you.

> What values is `gl_Position` supposed to take? `uf_Projection` seems to normalize the values, but when adding values (more than 2000) at center.x, it still works (correctly moved the screen).

`gl_Position` is the *clip space* position of the vertex. Now clip space is a bit hard to describe. The "normalization" you see here has to do with the fact that there is another space, the *normalized device coords* (NDC). And in the GL, the convention for NDC is such that the viewing volume is represented by the -1 <= x,y,z <=1  cube in NDC.

So if `x_ndc` is -1, the object will appear at the left border of your viewport, x=1 at the right borde, y=-1 at bottom border and so on. You also have clipping at z, so object which are too far away or are too near of the hypothetical camera position will also not be visible. (Note that the near clipping plane will also exclude everything which is behind the observer.)

The rule to transform from clip space to NDC is by dividing the clip space x,y and z vlaues by the clip space w value.
The rationale for this is that clip space represents a so called [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space), and the clip space coordinates are [homogenuous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). It would be far to much to explain the theory behind this in an StackOverflow article.

But what this means is that by setting `gl_Position.w` to `center.z`, the GL will later effectively divide `gl_Position.xyz` by `center.z` to reach NDC coordinates. Such a division basiaclly creates the perspective effect that points which are farther away appear closer together.

It is unclear to me if this is exactly what you want. Your current solution has the effect that increasing center.z will increase the object space range that is mapped to the viewing volume, so it does give a zoom effect. Let's consider the `x` coordinate:

```
x_ndc = (in_Position.x /  uf_Projection.x - center.x) / center.z
      = in_Position.x / (uf_Projection.x * center.z) - center.x / center.z
```

To put it the other way around, the object space `x` range you can see on the screen will be the inverse transformation applied to `x_ndc=-1` and `x_ndc=1`:

```
x_obj = (x_ndc + center.x/center.z) * (uf_Projection.x * center.z)
      = x_ndc * uf_Projection.x * center.z + center.x * uf_Projection.x
      = uf_Projection.x * (x_ndc * center.z + center.x);
```

So basically, the visibile object space range will be `center.xy +- uf_Projection.xy * center.z`.

> Is this the correct way to create a kind of "camera" effect? Or is there a better way? (the idea is that things that aren't on the screen, don't have to get rendered)

Conceptually, the steps are right. Usually, one uses transformation matrices to define the necessary steps. But in your case, directly applying the transformations as some multiplcations and additions is even more efficient (but less flexible).

> I'm using `uniform vec3 center` to manipulate the camera location. (I'm feeling it should be called an attribute, but I don't know for sure.

Actually, using a uniform for this is the right thing to do. Attributes are for values which can change per vertex. Uniforms are for values which are constant during the draw call (hence, are "uniform" for all shader invocations they are accesed by). Your camera specification should be the same for each vertex you are processing. Only the vertex position does vary between vertices, so that each vertex will end up at a different point with respect to some fixed camera location (and parameters).

Comment: You have no idea how much your clarification helped. :-) 
(I'm waiting an hour or so, then I'll mark as accepted :-) )